# Explicit form activation not working with startmenu when using the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE flag

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Have enabled the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE flag in CreateParams() in my application to prevent the application from stealing focus during startup (not actually needed in this small example, but needed in the much bigger real application with multiple forms).

When the form is clicked, `Activate()` is called.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
   public MyForm()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   protected override CreateParams CreateParams
   {
      get
      {
         int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;
         CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
         cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
         return cp;
      }
   }
   
   private void MyForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      label1.Text = "Clicked";
      Activate();
   }
}
```

This works fine in most cases, but when the Windows startmenu is opened and the form is clicked, the startmenu doesn't close (like it does when any other window is clicked).

The call to `Activate()` doesn't seem to fully activate the form when using NOACTIVATE in CreateParams().

Note 1: It actually works when running the application from Visual Studio, but not when starting the application using the .exe outside of VS.

Note 2: The application icon down in the taskbar starts to blink when the form is clicked.

Have tried to call *SetActiveWindow*, *SetForegroundWindow* with the window handle too, but that didn't help.

[image]

Is using .NET Framework 4.7.2 and Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Did you try to remove the `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` and then `Activate()` the form when you click the form? You can use the Win32 function `SetWindowLongPtr` to remove and add a style?

Comment: [Form.ShowWithoutActivation Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showwithoutactivation?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: Have you tried to simply add `protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation => true;` and remove the `CreateParams` override? This Window is meant to show up non-active but it can be activated after. Otherwise, you'd have to trigger CreateParams again, with a switch, to remove the style, then activate the Window again, which would upset the Taskbar anyway

Comment: Removing WS_EX_NOACTIVATE in CreateParams and adding ShowWithoutActivation => true works in this example application, but it causes the form to steal focus in my real/big application unfortunately. Will look into triggering CreateParams again as you suggested

Comment: It should not steal the Focus. Maybe you mean that this Form is simply shown on top of another? That's expected, but it's also expected that the Window is not actually the active Window. The opener should be the active Window. What happens if you press the `TAB` key?

Comment: In the real application a splashScreen-form is first shown, then a login-form and finally the application main form. It takes a while to start up. Can't get the mainform to NOT steal focus (from for example typing an email in Outlook) without WS_EX_NOACTIVATE on mainForm if the user has typed their password in the loginForm (so that form need to be activated to receive the pressed keyboard-keys).

Comment: Was able to change style on the window using SetWindowLong & SetWindowPos, but that didn't trigger another CreateParams unfortunately, see code here: https://pastebin.com/xRxx0AnJ Let me know if I should do it in some other way? Thanks